# Unable to use pip/ install mods with it

Tags: python, bash, pip

I know this question has been asked so many times on here but I still don't understand what I am doing wrong. I have Python 3.8.2, so pip apparently already comes with my program. I have a file in my Python 3.8 folder named 'Install Certificates.command' which when I run seems to be using pip. This is the only file I can find it being referenced. Whenever I try any command with pip though, either in the terminal or python shell, I'll either get invalid syntax (shell) or -bash: pip: command not found (Terminal).

Here's what my Terminal is looking like.

```
Samuels-MacBook-Air:~ SPATTERSON15$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
Samuels-MacBook-Air:~ SPATTERSON15$ pip --version
-bash: pip: command not found
Samuels-MacBook-Air:~ SPATTERSON15$ pip install openpyxl
-bash: pip: command not found
Samuels-MacBook-Air:~ SPATTERSON15$ python3.8.2
-bash: python3.8.2: command not found
Samuels-MacBook-Air:~ SPATTERSON15$ python3
Python 3.8.2 (v3.8.2:7b3ab5921f, Feb 24 2020, 17:52:18) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> pip install openpyxl
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install openpyxl
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: Try in **bash**: `python3 -m pip install openpyxl`

Answer (score 0):

You should know that pip cannot be run in a Python interpreter,it is to be run in a command line so that you can install packages and then use them in Python.
For you it says pip command not found because you would not have set your environment variables properly. So set the path of pip which will be in scripts folder of Python probably and update your environment variables.

Comment: I can't find any scripts folder, nor can I find any documentation with the name pip on my laptop. I'm on MacOS Sierra if that means anything

Comment: If you have installed python then there will be a folder corresponding it. Switch to that folder, there you will be able to find Scripts folder.

Comment: https://ibb.co/Bn56tGx This is everything that is in my python folder. Is something messed up with it?

Comment: This is the place where the executable ide of the python is most likely a shortcut kind of thing, you will have a more particular folder for Python where all its relevant files are there